# Does the id() function in python create new values?

Tags: python

I was just playing around with the id() function & noticed that if you pass a value that you haven't assigned to a variable yet, instead of giving an error it returns a memory address.
So does the id() function assign that value to an empty memory location?

```
>>> print id(18)
14569728
>>> b = 18
>>> print id(b)
14569728
>>> print id('check')
140297315282112
>>> c = 'check'
>>> print id(c)
140297315282112
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values/literals *are* objects, so `id()` will *always* return a valid result for them. Beyond that, in CPython integer literals from -1 through 256 as well as short string literals are [**interned**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), so they will have a constant ID after they have been accessed for the first time.