# Python variable allocation and `id` keyword

Tags: python, parsing, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)
>   [Why (0-6) is -6 = False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false)

So, while playing with a bit with `id` (python 2.6.5), I noticed the following (shell session):

```
>>> a = 1
>>> id(a)
140524904
>>> b = 1
>>> id(b)
140524904
```

Of course, as soon as I modify one of the variables it gets assigned to a new memory address, i.e.

```
>>> b += 1
>>> id(b)
140524892
```

Is it the normal behavior to initially assign both variables that have identical values to the same memory location or just an optimization of i.e. CPython?

P.s. I spent a little time browsing around the code in `parser`, but couldn't find where and how variables are allocated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: Thank you both, I'll mark mine as duplicate

Comment: I think this answer would be of help - <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/9475950/805427">literals from -1 to 256 and some short strings are interned</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned by glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975850/824425), this is an implementation detail of CPython. If you look at `Objects/longobject.c` in the source code for CPython (e.g. version 3.3.0), you'll find the answer to what's happening:

```
#if NSMALLNEGINTS + NSMALLPOSINTS > 0
/* Small integers are preallocated in this array so that they
   can be shared.
   The integers that are preallocated are those in the range
   -NSMALLNEGINTS (inclusive) to NSMALLPOSINTS (not inclusive).
*/
static PyLongObject small_ints[NSMALLNEGINTS + NSMALLPOSINTS];
```

This explains why, after `a = 1; b = 1`, `a is b` will be `True`, even when you say `a += 2; b +=2; a -= 2; b -= 2`. Whenever a number is calculated to have a value that fits in this array, the resulting object is simply picked from this array instead, saving a bit of memory.

You can figure out the bounds of this `small_ints` array using a function like this:

```
def binary_search(predicate, lo, hi):
    while lo + 1 < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) / 2
        if predicate(mid):
            lo = mid
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo

def is_small_int(n):
    p = n + 1
    q = n + 1
    return (p - 1) is (q - 1)

def min_neg_small_int():
    p, q = -1, -1
    if p is not q:
        return 0
    while p is q:
        p += p
        q += q
    return binary_search(is_small_int, p / 2, p) - 1

def max_pos_small_int():
    p, q = 1, 1
    if p is not q:
        return 0
    while p is q:
        p += p
        q += q
    return binary_search(is_small_int, p / 2, p)

def small_int_bounds():
    return (min_neg_small_int(), max_pos_small_int())
```

For my build (Python 2.7, 64-bit Windows build), `small_int_bounds() == (-5, 256)`. This means that numbers between `-5` and `256` (inclusive) are shared through the `small_ints` array in `Objects/longobject.c`.

-edit- I see [elssar noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975762/python-variable-allocation-and-id-keyword/13977024#comment19284877_13975762) that there is a [similar answer about interning of some literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475950/805427). This fact is also mentioned [in the documentation for `PyInt_FromLong`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong), as mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/824425).

Comment: thank you very much for your thorough answer (and also for the pointer in the python source -- it would take a while to spot this)! and thanks to all the other useful answers and comments!

Comment: The only reason it took me a while to find it is because I was looking for something with `int` in its name. But once you find this source file, it's pretty much the first thing in there. That might be because, and I quote, "`/* XXX The functional organization of this file is terrible */`" ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. In python all variables are pointers to some objects. Even number.
2. Number is immutable object. So, CPython not need to create a new object with the same value.
3. This does not mean that CPython will always use the same objects.
4. In your first example variables `a` and `b` point to the same object.
5. When your make `b += 1` you "create" new object `2`.

Comment: +1 I knew that tuples and strings were immutable, but never occurred to me that numbers are too (or probably I missed that one).

Answer (score 2):

Here the term "variables" must be precised: there are objects at one hand, and names which are bound to objects at the other hand.

If you do `a = b = 1`, both `a` and `b` are bound to the same object representing `1`.

If you do `a = 1; b = 1`, I think it is a CPython detail that it is the same. Generally, an implementation could choose to have two objects both representing `1` and using them both here. But as that would be a waste of memory, it is generally not done in this way.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` both refer to the same object in memory (`1`), with the ID `140524904`. Once you do `b += 1` you have `2`, which is located elsewhere.

Comment: what about a=1000 and b=1000?